# Why after recovery, the graphics files are empty? How to recover them completely?

Tags: data-recovery

My HDD (having both Windows and Linux OS) crashed. I used the recovery tool to get back my photos back (graphics file). After going through the files, I found that the names of some files are correctly recovered but the size is being shown zero (instead of file size being approximately 2-10MB). Also, the image viewer says not supported file. What may be the possible reason and solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is files are described in special table where is also described the blocks who "make" the file. If you get this table corrupted you do not have anymore the information where the content of the file is located. Of course there is more than one copy of this table but if your harddisk is heavy damaged you may find all of them corrupted.

Also you may have corrupted/unreadable the blocks where the content of the files is stored. So recovery program can't read it (or read garbage).